# Cordova 6.3.1 plugin update issue

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm making a `cordova 6.3.1` app with `Kapsel` plugins. Now I'm trying to customise the default `Kapsel` login screen in the plugin's view and controller files.

However, on running `cordova prepare` the changes in the plugin files are not replicated in `platforms/android/assets/www` directory as well as the app. Upon running `cordova build` the changes are lost.

The versions are as follows:

```
cordova v6.3.1
SP 14
node 8.10.0
npm 5.8.0
```

Comment: can you describe what files are you editing? (like location of the files and things like that)

Comment: For the view changes to be replicated I have to edit the `view` files in `platforms\android\platform_www` which is working fine. However, for the controller files I am editing the files in `plugins/` directory because I have to customise the default kapsel logon plugin which is not getting replicated in the app.

Comment: You're developing your plugin directly in the plugins folder of your cordova app?

Comment: I'm customizing the exisiting kapsel logon plugin directly from the plugins folder.